# Contiki for cc2530dk

Tags: contiki

Recently I am working on `Contiki` and `cc2530dk`.

What I want to do is to run `Contiki` on `cc2530dk`. As far as I know, I need to `make` a hex file, and then burn it to `cc2530dk`. However, I meet trouble in making a hex file for hello-world.

I download `InstantContiki-2.6`, and run in `VMware`. Then I changed directory to `contiki-sensinode-cc-ports` from [here](https://github.com/g-oikonomou/contiki-sensinode).

I can run `make` in `examples/hello-world/`. But I don't know how to create hex file. I tried:

```
make TARGET=cc2530dk
```

but failed. I got Error:

```
make: sdcc: Command not found
make: *** [obj_cc2530dk/rimeaddr.rel] Error 127
```

What I want to do is: run `contiki` on `cc2530dk`.

Comment: EDIT: Thanks for @Daniele, I installed SDCC successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the Small Device C Compiler (SDCC). To do that, follow [this guide](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/8051-Requirements) from Contiki wiki.

Comment: Excuse me~ your link for "this guide" is "Down for maintenace". I think you are talking about the guide of installing SDCC. And When I type: sdcc -v. There is some imformation, but I don't read it carefully. I will check it soon whether or not I installed SDCC. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check with cmd sdcc -v. If it does not give like below:

```
SDCC : mcs51/pic16/hc08 3.1.1 #7100 (Aug  5 2013) (Linux)
```

Then, install SDCC and then build tool chain.